# Operator for 2D button gizmo is not called

Tags: python, add-on, operator, gizmo

I have a simple `GIZMO_GT_button_2d` that should invoke an operator when clicked upon but this is not happening. I can call the operator directly with `bpy.ops`, but nothing happens when I click on the little gizmo

My operator

```
class CustomOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "run.forest"
    bl_label = "Run Forest"
    bl_description = "Run, Forest, Run!"

    def __init__(self):
        print("Start")

    def __del__(self):
        print("End")
    
    def execute(self, context):
        print("Execute")
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

And then I build my gizmo like this

```
class CustomGizmos(bpy.types.GizmoGroup):
    bl_idname = "CustomGizmos"
    bl_label = "Custom gizmos"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_options = {'PERSISTENT', 'SCALE'}
    
    @classmethod
    def setup_keymap(cls, keyconfig):
        keymap = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new('run_forest')
        keymap.keymap_items.new('run.forest', 'P', 'PRESS')
        return keymap
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True
    
    def draw_prepare(self, context):
        r_xpos = context.region.width - 30
        for gizmo in self.gizmos:
            gizmo.matrix_basis[0][3] = r_xpos
            gizmo.matrix_basis[1][3] = 48
            r_xpos += 55

    def setup(self, context):
        mpr = self.gizmos.new("GIZMO_GT_button_2d")
        mpr.bl_idname = "RunForestButton"
        mpr.icon = 'PLAY'
        mpr.draw_options = {'BACKDROP', 'OUTLINE'}
        mpr.target_set_operator('run.forest')
        mpr.alpha = 1.0
        mpr.color = 0.5, 0.5, 0.5
        mpr.color_highlight = 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
        mpr.alpha_highlight = 0.3
        mpr.scale_basis = (80 * 0.35) / 2
        mpr.use_tooltip = True
        mpr.show_drag = False
        mpr.use_draw_value = True
        
register_class(CustomOperator)
register_class(CustomGizmos)

#bpy.ops.run.forest()
```

I can see the operator's description as a tooltip when I hover the gizmo, but clicking it doesn't do anything. I also tried with `invoke`. The keyboard shortcut that I am trying to assign to the same operator doesn't call it, either.

Looks like this is a hard one. I have added constructor/destructor and what I see is that the object is deleted when registered (the console outputs `End`)

**New update**
Apparently, it's the `setup_keymap` that messes it up. I remove it and the gizmo works. Don't know why yet